# run a javascript for each child element in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, get-childitem

I want ot make a new function `function showdiv(toshow)`
     "toshow" should have the name of the div to show "div1" or "div2"
     and then I want to get the inner divs inside the contentdiv and check, for each div, if the `name is == toshow`, run

```
$( document.getElementById($div).show( "fast" );
```

else if the id of div != toshow

```
$( document.getElementById(@div) ).hide( "fast");
```

how to write the function and the for look

Please write it in a basic and readable code.

```js
 function showdiv(toshow) {
 }

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hide demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="showdiv('div1');">Klicka här för div1</a></br>
<a href="#" onclick="showdiv('div2');">Klicka här för div2</a>
<button id="div1show">show div1</button>
<button id="div2show">Show div2</button>
<div id="contentdiv" >
    <div id="div1" name="div1" class="inner" style="display:none;" background: "red">
      <span>Once</span> <span>upon</span> <span>a</span>
      <span>time</span> <span>there</span> <span>were</span>
      <span>three</span> <span>programmers...</span>
    </div>

    <div id="div2" name="div2" class="inner" style="display:none;" background: "blue">
         <div id="login"> 
             <button id="btn">btn</button>
        </div>
         <p>text ... text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  
function showdiv(toshow){
    $("#contentdiv div").hide("fast"); //Hide all divs
    $("#" + toshow).show("fast"); //Show one specific div
}    
    

$( "#div2show" ).click(function() {
  $( document.getElementById("div1") ).hide( "fast");
  $( document.getElementById("div2")).show( "fast" );
});

$( "#div1show" ).click(function() {
  $( document.getElementById("div2") ).hide( "fast");
  $( document.getElementById("div1")).show( "fast" );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

```
 $("#div2show").click(function() {
   $(document.getElementById("div1")).hide("fast");
   $(document.getElementById("div2")).show("fast");
 });

 $("#div1show").click(function() {
   $(document.getElementById("div2")).hide("fast");
   $(document.getElementById("div1")).show("fast");
 });
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="$('.content').load('selectlandfromdb.php');">Klicka här</a>
<button id="div1show">show div1</button>
<button id="div2show">Show div2</button>
<div id="contentdiv">
  <div id="div1" class="inner" style="`enter code here`display:none;" background: "red">
    <span>Once</span>  <span>upon</span>  <span>a</span>
    <span>time</span>  <span>there</span>  <span>were</span>
    <span>three</span>  <span>programmers...</span>
  </div>

  <div id="div2" class="inner" style="display:none;" background: "blue">
    <p>text ... text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to say I have seen this for the first time: `$(document.getElementById("div1"))`. Also your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite hard to understand what you want to achieve, but I assume you want to be able to specify a name of the div, show this div, and hide all the others.

This could be done like that:

```
function showdiv(toshow){
    $("#contentdiv > div").hide("fast"); //Hide all divs
    $("#" + toshow).show("fast"); //Show one specific div
}
```

Then you can run the function like that:

```
showdiv("div1"); //Hides all divs, only shows the one with id 'div1'
```

Also, you don't need to write:

```
$(document.getElementById("div1"));
```

To get a jquery element by id, you just have to specify that you're picking the element by its id by writing `#` before the name. Do it like that:

```
$("#div1")
```

Comment: To clarify for the OP, this is plain javascript: `document.getElementById('div1')` and this is the jQuery equivalent: `$('#div1')`

Comment: thnans, but the problemis when I add new divs inside div1 and div2

Comment: @Harald As to the problem with adding divs to div1 and div2, could you describe what the problem exactly is? If it's the fact that it hid all of the divs, even those inside the other divs, then that's my bad. Didn't consider that. In my post, I updated my function and it should work right now. The problem was that I all divs using `$("#contentdiv div")`. By using `$("#contentdiv > div")` I now only select direct children-elements of the `#contentdiv`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you use jQuery, you can write something like this:

```
$("#contentdiv>div").each(function(e) {
    if ($(e).attr("name") == "toShow") $(e).show("fast");
    else $(e).hide("fast");
})
```

Note: Code is not tested